# Prove $f(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap \dotsb \cap A_n)=f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) \cap f(A_3) \cap \dotsb \cap f(A_n)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: R \to R$ be a one to one function. For any collection of subsets $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dotsc A_n$ of $R$, prove that
$$f(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap \dotsb \cap A_n)=f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) \cap f(A_3) \cap \dotsb \cap f(A_n)$$
How to do this? Can you give me any startup tips? Thanks!

Here's the definitions and theorems I used to come up with a solution,

1. $x∈A_1∩A_2$ => $x∈A_1$ and $x∈A_2$
2. $A ⊂ B$ and $B ⊂ A$ => $A = B$

Comment: What do those things mean? (*I* know what they mean - but it's important that you unpackage the definitions and meanings. Sometimes proving a claim is as simple as knowing explicitly what the claim is saying.)

Comment: Perhaps you can try to prove $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$ as a simple case and generalize from there via induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_1, A_2 \subset \Bbb R$. We show that $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$.

Let $y \in f(A_1 \cap A_2)$. Then there exists a $x \in A_1 \cap A_2$, such that $f(x) = y$. Since $x \in A_1$, we have $y = f(x) \in f(A_1)$, and since $x \in A_2$, we have $y = f(x) \in f(A_2)$, so $y \in f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$. This shows that $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subset f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$.

Let $y \in f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$, then $y \in f(A_1)$ and $y \in f(A_2)$. This means that there exists a $x \in A_1$, such that $f(x) = y$, and there exists a $x' \in A_2$, such that $f(x') = y$. So we have $f(x) = f(x')$, and since $f$ is injective, it follows that $x = x'$. Since $x \in A_1$ and $x = x' \in A_2$, we must have $x \in A_1 \cap A_2$, so $y = f(x) \in f(A_1 \cap A_2)$, which shows that $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) \subset f(A_1 \cap A_2)$.

You can now generalize this for $A_1, \ldots, A_n \subset \Bbb R$ by an induction argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot @aexl !!! :D That is a very clear explanation. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Let be $y\in f(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n)$, then there is $x\in A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n$, such that $f(x)=y$, a fortiori $x\in A_i$, for every $i=1,\cdots, n.$  So $y\in f(A_i)$, for every $i=1,\cdots, n.$

Thus, $y\in f(A_1)\cap f(A_2)\cap\cdots\cap f(A_n).$

Try the other sense of afirmation.